# Swift- Text field formatting update while editing

Tags: uitableview, swift, core-data, uitextfield

I have a function for formatting my text field as a phone number, but this function is only working after I save my managed object context. For example, I have a UITableView with static cells for text fields as a contact form. When I'm creating a new contact (before I've saved the contact) the text field for phone number doesn't get formatted by my function, but after I save that contact and reopen it, then go and enter a phone number it gets formatted properly. I'm trying to figure out why this is, and what I am do about it so that the number gets formatted in either case. Here's the function that I'm using to format the phone number.

```
func textField(textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersInRange range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        if textField == phoneTxt {
            var newString = (textField.text as NSString).stringByReplacingCharactersInRange(range, withString: string)
            var components = newString.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.decimalDigitCharacterSet().invertedSet)
            var decimalString = "".join(components) as NSString
            var length = decimalString.length
            var hasLeadingOne = length > 0 && decimalString.characterAtIndex(0) == (1 as unichar)

            if length == 0 || (length > 10 && !hasLeadingOne) || length > 11 {
                var newLength = (textField.text as NSString).length + (string as NSString).length - range.length as Int

                return (newLength > 10) ? false : true
            }
            var index = 0 as Int
            var formattedString = NSMutableString()

            if hasLeadingOne {
                formattedString.appendString("1 ")
                index += 1
            }
            if (length - index) > 3 {
                var areaCode = decimalString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(index, 3))
                formattedString.appendFormat("(%@) ", areaCode)
                index += 3
            }
            if length - index > 3 {
                var prefix = decimalString.substringWithRange(NSMakeRange(index, 3))
                formattedString.appendFormat("%@-", prefix)
                index += 3
            }

            var remainder = decimalString.substringFromIndex(index)
            formattedString.appendString(remainder)
            textField.text = formattedString
            return false
        } else {
            return true
        }
    }
`
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems when the form is used to create a *new* object, you somehow have not set the delegate of the text field. Check if the posted function is being called at all in this case.

Comment: how would I check if the text field has a delegate set?

Comment: Set a breakpoint in one of the delegate methods. If it does not get hit, you did not set the delegate.